# How to improve memorizing ability?

Tags: brain, tea, memory

I'm a student,  how can I improve my memory ? 
 Also, I heard that Matcha tea is good for students,  is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Train your Brain.

its not the supplement in the market which will boost your memory application, althgough you can take Omega supplements which is good for brain stuff and heart.